# Visual Studio Community 2015 with Xamarin Compile not ended

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

I has just download Visual Studio Community 2015 and choose install the crosss platform C#/Xamarin.  After that, I start try out the mobile project by choose blank apps(portable).  I add layout for the Adroid project and add one button.  Then I try to build the Android project only by choosing the emulator Adroid 4.4 - API 19.  But Visual Studio keep compiling and never end.  I wait for 1 hour, it still compiling.  What's wrong or any component I not install or setting I miss out, please help.  Thank you very much

Comment: try using a real device !  (also don't forget to check configuration manager , deployment should be selected there  .

Comment: I try to use real device which running Android 4.4 and change the build to release but it also the same.  It seem like need downloading something.  Not sure what the problem

Comment: try one thing , go to Appdata , delete the xamarin folder content , let it download again(keep checking it size meanwhile to assure that it is downloading content  . 
also 8gm ram helps run new Vs community better ! .
some other tips i ll give you which will solve ur problem, once i switch to windows (8 hours from now)

Comment: i try delete that folder many time...some time build half way will mention missing some xamarin component.  I will try again later with more fast internet speed, because I found that it need download a huge file when compiling but is it everytime compile also need download?  Or only download once and future will need not download anymore.

Comment: It happens , when u have incomplete Vs setup .
Step wise process i am telling you .
1.  Get a fast internet 
2. delete xamarin folder content .
3. delete the bin/obj/package content from project directory .
4. make sure you have all the installed all the needed android sdks .
5. find configuartion manager (tools -> config...)  deployment should be checked .
6 rebuild the solution